# Using optional arguments in R function

Tags: r, function, arguments, option-type

I want to use optional argument `logbase = NULL` in my following function. However could not figure out the best practice. Any hints, please.

```
fn1 <- function(x, logbase = NULL){
  logbase <- ifelse(test = is.null(logbase) | 10, yes = 10, no = logbase)
  out <- log(x = x, base = logbase)
  return(out)
}

fn1(x = 10, logbase = NULL)
1
```

Wrong Answer

```
fn1(x = 10, logbase = 2)
1
```

Wrong Answer

```
fn1(x = 10, logbase = exp(1))
1
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the current approach and how would you like to improve it?

Comment: Thanks @NelsonGon for your interest in my problem. Please see my edits.

Comment: I think your function is fine, except the '| 10' always evaluates to TRUE, as converting any non-zero number to a Boolean evaluates as TRUE. You could just remove the | 10 part

Comment: Thanks @hodgenovice for your comment. However, removing `|10` part is also not working as expected. Any thoughts.

Comment: You want | test == 10. Also use if and else instead of ifelse.

Comment: @Roland test is not an object so you can't evaluate it - it's simply the first argument of the ifelse function. I think you meant | logbase == 10? If so, this can still have issues when logbase is NULL

Comment: Right. Who names arguments in ifelse? Anyway, if (is.null(logbase) || logbase == 10) ... else ... Or just set logbase = 10 as default. No, reason to use NULL as default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My suggestion**
I think the `| 10` part is causing the issue, and since when `logbase` is 10, you get the same whether test evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE`, you can just remove it. I know you said in a comment this isn't working as expected, but it seems to for me - if it`s still not for you, feel free to comment.

```
fn1 <- function(x, logbase = NULL){
  logbase <- ifelse(test = is.null(logbase), yes = 10, no = logbase)
  out <- log(x = x, base = logbase)
  return(out)
}

fn1(x = 10, logbase = NULL)    # 1
fn1(x = 10, logbase = 2)       # 3.321928
fn1(x = 10, logbase = exp(1))  # 2.302585
```

**What the issue with your code was**
The issue is anything with `| 10` will always evaluate to `TRUE`. This is because the `|` operator will convert the arguments on both sides to `logical`, so something like `is.null(2) | 10` is equivalent to `as.logical(is.null(2)) | as.logical(10)` which evaluates to `F | T` which is `T`.

To be clear, `| 10` is not related to logbase. What you were looking for is presumably `| logbase == 10`. This is fine, except when logbase is `NULL`, you run into issues because `NULL == 10` doesn't evaluate to `T` or `F` (it's `logical(0)`).
You can fix this by using `||`, rather than `|`, which would only evaluate `logbase == 10` if `is.null(logbase)` is `FALSE`, because if the first half of a `||` is `TRUE`, then it simply returns `TRUE` without evaluating the second half.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variant:

```
fn1 <- function(x, logbase = NULL){
   if(is.null(logbase)||logbase==10){
   logbase=10
    #logbase <- ifelse(test = is.null(logbase) | 10, yes = 10, no = logbase)
    out <- log(x = x, base = logbase)
    return(out)
  }
 else{
   log(x = x, base = logbase)#?exp(logbase)
 }


}
```

Test:

```
fn1(x = 10, logbase = 2)
[1] 3.321928
```

Comment: Thanks @NelsonGon for your answer. However, `fn1(x = 10, logbase = NULL)` and `fn1(x = 10)` throw the following error: `Error in if (is.null(logbase) | logbase == 10) { :   argument is of length zero`. Any thoughts.

Comment: Try using ||, rather than |

Comment: Right! I think you just need to set base 10 as the default.

Comment: @hodgenovice: Use of `||` throws the error: `Error in log(x = x, base = logbase) : invalid argument 'base' of length 0`.